# label z missing compilation error when using break z

Tags: java

```
package brea;

public class BreakExample {

    static String o ="";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        z:
        o = o +2;
    for(int x = 3 ; x < 8 ; x++){
        if(x == 4) break;
        if(x==6) break z;
        o = o+x;
    }
        System.out.println(o);  
    }
}
```

In the above code i get a compilation error as label z is missing. what is the reason ? What can be a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

[A label is followed by a statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7). In your case, that statement is only the

```
o = o + 2;
```

So `z` is only in scope for that statement.

> The scope of a label of a labeled statement is the immediately
>   contained Statement.

If you want `z` to be in scope for the `for` statement, add a block statement

```
z: {
    o = o + 2;
    for (int x = 3; x < 8; x++) {
        if (x == 4)
            break;
        if (x == 6)
            break z;
        o = o + x;
    }
}
```